# Databound Datagridview Combobox showing day of week from datetime

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datagridview, combobox

I have added a combobox to a datagridview that is already bound to a datasource.  The data I was looking at was Strings and that worked fine.  Now I want to add another combobox which picks up a date value and shows the day of the week.  The time is shown a separate column, so the user can pick a date then add a time.

The datasource for the Datagridview is a datatable which has a datetime column called starttime

I think this isn't working because the combobox vales are just dates, and the dataproperty values are dates and times.

I've added a complete worked example below.

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable

    dt1.Columns.Add("StartDate", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
    dt1.Columns.Add("StringData", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt1.Columns.Add("NumberData", Type.GetType("System.Double"))

    Dim newrow As DataRow
    newrow = dt1.NewRow
    newrow("StartDate") = Date.Parse("24/07/2015 12:00")
    newrow("StringData") = "AAA"
    newrow("NumberData") = 123
    dt1.Rows.Add(newrow)

    newrow = dt1.NewRow
    newrow("StartDate") = Date.Parse("25/07/2015 09:00")
    newrow("StringData") = "ABC"
    newrow("NumberData") = 234
    dt1.Rows.Add(newrow)

    newrow = dt1.NewRow
    newrow("StartDate") = Date.Parse("26/07/2015 10:00")
    newrow("StringData") = "DEF"
    newrow("NumberData") = 678
    dt1.Rows.Add(newrow)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt1

    Dim dt2 As New DataTable

    dt2.Columns.Add("DayDate", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
    dt2.Columns.Add("DayName", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt2.Columns.Add("Test", Type.GetType("System.Double"))

    Dim newrow2 As DataRow
    newrow2 = dt2.NewRow
    newrow2("DayDate") = Date.Parse("24/07/2015")
    newrow2("DayName") = Date.Parse("24/07/2015").ToString("dddd")
    newrow2("Test") = 123
    dt2.Rows.Add(newrow2)

    newrow2 = dt2.NewRow
    newrow2("DayDate") = Date.Parse("25/07/2015")
    newrow2("DayName") = Date.Parse("25/07/2015").ToString("dddd")
    newrow2("Test") = 234
    dt2.Rows.Add(newrow2)

    newrow2 = dt2.NewRow
    newrow2("DayDate") = Date.Parse("26/07/2015")
    newrow2("DayName") = Date.Parse("26/07/2015").ToString("dddd")
    newrow2("Test") = 678
    dt2.Rows.Add(newrow2)

    Dim comboBoxColumn2 As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    comboBoxColumn2.DataPropertyName = "StartDate"

    comboBoxColumn2.DisplayMember = "DayName"
    comboBoxColumn2.ValueMember = "DayDate"

    comboBoxColumn2.DataSource = dt2

    comboBoxColumn2.Name = "WorkingDay"

    DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, comboBoxColumn2)

End Sub
```

I get an error:

> System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

I'm guessing this is because the value in the combobox is 24/08/2015 and the value in the datatsource of the datagridview (the DataPropertyName) is 24/08/2015 08:00.

If I change these two values:

```
    comboBoxColumn2.DataPropertyName = "NumberData"

    comboBoxColumn2.DisplayMember = "Test"
```

The sample works as expected with no error.

How can I set the DataPropertyName to just the Date and not the Date & Time?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. What DataSource are you adding to the DataGridView? (note that date vs. date & time is not an issue)

Comment: I'm interested that you think the date and time isn't the problem, I saw a similar error when I had a value in the DGV datasource which wasn't in the comboboxcolumn datasource.  
Earlier in the code I have: DataGridView1.DataSource = HoursTable
HoursTable includes the datetime column called starttime

Comment: The DateTime type is very flexible (actually, there was a question about this a couple of days ago). You can parse almost any date/time (even with various separators; logically, as far as you don't use ParseExact) and an error would almost never be triggered. One of the few scenarios were an error is triggered is inputting completely wrong values (e.g., 13 as month); other than that, you can input almost anything.

Comment: I come back to highlight (I read another question right now refreshing my knowledge about all this weird-columns in DataGridView), that your approach of inserting the column is actually quite good. I said that this was too messy (this comment has now been deleted by moderators I guess, but no big deal) because adding via DataSource and Columns is usually not required (even a bad idea). Here is not required either, but it represents a pretty good option. This was all: I might prefer to not continue helping you, but I am responsible for all the not-completely-right information I deliver :)